# Job submitted on Epson L3250 automatically stops (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: printing

I have installed a new EPSON L3250 printer with my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop. It is presently connected with a USB cable (not Wi-Fi network). Whenever I submit a job (even a test-print), it is successfully accepted in the print queue and is almost immediately stopped (the job is stopped -- not the printer). There is no way to restart it.

The following information may be of further use:

1. The printer is enabled and idle before job submission.
2. device for EPSON-L3250-Series: usb://EPSON/L3250%20Series?serial=584148543134363347&interface=1
3. Driver: Epson L3250 Series - epson-inkjet-printer-escpr 1.7.21-1lsb3.2 (Seiko Epson Corporation LSB 3.2)
4. Printer status after job submission: Idle - Rendering completed

Shall appreciate any help in resolving the problem.

Comment: Noticed something more on "Print" menu -> Color: Printer profile: Unspecified profile. Can it be related?

Comment: One more observation: When I use the driver "Epson ActionPrinter 3250 Foomatic/ap3250 (recommended)", it prints in grayscale. There is no way to select color mode.